# Como publicar App no visual studio 2017 com ASP.MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde, estou etudando ASP.MVC 5 e fiz um app de teste, publiquei ele no visual studio exportando para um diretório e tentei subir o mesmo no IIS no Windows 10.

Fiz todo procedimento descrito no site [ASP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/deploying-asp-net-web-project-publicando-e-configurando-sua-aplicacao-em-producao/22840)  e ao tentar abrir aparece Erro HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden. Fui no IIS, dei permissão e ao tentar abrir novamente, ele lista o conteúdo e não abre o APP.
O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Deu permissão no que? No diretório da aplicação?

Comment: Permissão de pesquisa no diretório, acho que não é necessário, apenas segui as recomendações do erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ronaldo, tenta fazer esse procedimento, eu tive o mesmo problema e consegui resolver assim:
http://ninjacode.com.br/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-contents-of-this-directory/ 
Espero que ajude.

Comment: Leonardo, obrigado pela resposta, no caso eu já tinha dado a permissão de pesquisa conforme o link que me passou, o estranho é que ele está listando o conteúdo, porém não abre o APP. Em java(estou migrando devido a necessidade da empresa) tinha sempre um arquivo inicial tipo um index, porém em ASP não.

Comment: No ASP net esse "index" é o Home do seu  controller principal que você configura no route.config tem a rota padrão lá, você criou o home?

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso o problema era a versão do Asp.NET instalada junto ao IIS. Veja na imagem abaixo se você possui os componentes instalados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, vá no IIS e altere o pool do seu aplicativo pra versão correta do .NET Framework no meu caso, criei uma aplicação Asp.NET MVC5 .NET framework 4.5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]